# Expanding bootstraps dropdown-submenu, keeping it inline with the parent menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want the submenu from the dropdown nav to be inline with its parent. The first link is inline fine because - .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {top:0;} but with the other links in the submenu the "top" position changes in relation to its parent menu link. Please look at http://bootply.com/66517

```
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="#">More options</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="#">More options</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="#">More options</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                </li>
                                <hr>
                            </ul>
                            </li>           
                        </ul>
```

Comment: for this you have to target that particular childs by css

Comment: I was afraid you would say that! Could be done that way but if you had the links (menu items) changing on a daily basis so would the amount of childs.

Comment: yeah am also thinking that way but your condition is unique. so the trick is unique. and also it is not the standard i think. is it?

Comment: hmmm, I might have to restructure away from the bootstrap way for it not to be unique

Comment: i got a way to achieve this give me some mins. first i'll confirm it then i'll tell you wait for my next comment

Comment: yeah i got the answer @Tom Rudge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**you can try this**

this will works fine

```
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: static !important;;
}
```

you can find this css in you min. version css of bootstrap but i prefer you modified it on that particular page in which you include this dropdown.

Comment: As easy as that! I knew there was a simpler way than using childs.

Comment: yeah you are right but we have to think harder for this hahahhaha :-) anyways thanks for give me a challenge like this